# How to expand div according to position in viewport

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to get a div to expand div to always fill the viewport;
at the moment i calculate the if the div is left ,rigth above or below the center of the viewport and expand accordingly.

I would prefer if the div would expand to center in the viewport if possible. atm the moment i am just adjusting the margin to allow the div to expand sideways. but if the expanded div is big it can expand passed the viewport on a side while having enough space on the otherside.
this has to be in vannilla javascript. My current code follows:

```
function calculateExpandDir(el) {
    var ele = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    var windowH = window.innerHeight;
    var windowW = window.innerWidth;
    var expandDir = {}
    if (ele.left + (ele.width / 2) >= window.innerWidth / 2) { expandDir.horizontal = "left" } else { expandDir.horizontal = "right" }
    if (ele.top + (ele.height / 2) >= window.innerHeight / 2) { expandDir.vertical = "up" } else { expandDir.vertical = "down" }

    return expandDir
}

function expandEl(el) {
    var expandedHeight = parseFloat(el.getAttribute('data-height'));
    var expandedWidth = parseFloat(el.getAttribute('data-width'));
    var originalWidth = parseFloat(el.getAttribute('data-orig-width'));
    var originalHeight = parseFloat(el.getAttribute('data-orig-height'));

    var marginTop = 0;
    var marginRight = 0;
    var marginBottom = 0;
    var marginLeft = 0;
    var dir = calculateExpandDir(el)
    console.log("expand to " + dir.vertical + dir.horizontal)
    if (dir.horizontal == "right") {

    }

    if (dir.horizontal == "left") {
        marginLeft = -(expandedWidth - originalWidth);
    }

    if (dir.vertical == "up") {
        marginTop = -(expandedHeight - originalHeight)
    }

    if (dir.vertical == "down") {
    };

    el.style.position = "absolute";
    el.style.height = expandedHeight+"px";
    el.style.width = expandedWidth + "px";
    el.style.transition = "all 0.5s ease-in-out";
    el.style.marginTop = marginTop+"px";
    el.style.marginBottom = marginBottom+"px";
    el.style.marginLeft = marginLeft+"px";
    el.style.marginRight = marginRight+"px";
}
```

I figured i have to calculate the ammount of space on each side of the div and expand the div proportionally to the ammount of space available so it will become centered but i am stuck on how to do this at the moment

EDIT:
https://codepen.io/sereal_killer/pen/eGZaNo
in this example the divs expand depending on their position. the center div is a cheat as it has the data attribute to tell it to expand in both directions.

i want the divs to expand to fill the screen depending on the available room (they have a max height and width).
if i have a centered div like in the example i want it to know it has equal room on both sides and expand equally left and right.
if it is a bit more to the right i want it to expand to still be centered.
the caveat is that it cannot leave where it originated. it cant pop out and just appear in the center. If i have time i will draw a picture aswell

Comment: #myDiv { width: 100%; }

Comment: so you need a div that will take whole viewport? can you post your html? I dont think you need JS for this, css will be fine I hope

Comment: This can be done in CSS with a variety of solutions. One is to use `flex` based design. Another to calculate dimensions based on the viewport width. For instance `.div {width:calc(100vw - 50px);margin:0 auto 0 auto}`. There are many questions in stackoverflow that deal with this.

Comment: .fullVIewport{ position: fixed; left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0; } will do the trick

Comment: can you post a picture of what you have and what you want please

Comment: i will try and make a fiddle or something tomorow. There are more pitfalls. like it has to stay connected the the div it is originating from.  it is not a simple fit to center. it has to expand from the div and strech out to meet the dimentions and if possible become centered.

Comment: @JSB okay, lets take a look on your jsfiddle (would be better if you'll use stackoverflow snippet tool - theres a button in edit panel)